# I'm having trouble correcting network credentials in my c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp

I'm trying to make a c# winform function so that when i press a button it sends an email to the email address given in a text box but there's something wrong with NetworkCredentials.

P.S I'm new to c# winforms

[image]

Comment: don't post screenshots of code. post code as formatted text.  also don't say "there's something wrong". post the actual error message. if you hover the mouse over that red underlined word it will tell you that you're missing a using statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't know `NetworkCredential`. You must specify the Namespace this class is defined in.

So either use `System.Net.NetworkCredential` or add `using System.Net;` to the top of your file so you don't have to type `System.Net.` everytime you want to use members of that namespace. This is ok until there have two classes with the same name. Then you must specify one of them explicitly.